# Twitter connect without using @anywhere

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created a twitter application and I need it to have "Connect" button that allows user to connect their twitter account with the app. Thanks to it, the application could automatically send new tweets when user is logged in to their twitter account. I have tried to use @anywhere but user has to re-connect each time when session expires. I need it to be persistent (like facebook connect).

Do you have any idea how to do that easily?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter). It is less JavaScript then @anywhere but it gives you more control over the integration. You will use your own sessions and can set how long they last to match your needs.